# Setting the background color on a selected row on an ASP.Net ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Currently I'm setting the background color of the row being edited by doing the following in the edititemtemplate.

```
<tr id="row" runat="server" enableviewstate="true" style="background-color: #5CB8DF">
```

A sorting requirement changed and the client wants to have the last edited record appear at the top of the listview. So after the save, the ListView is getting updated as I am using AJAX and not taking it out of edit mode. If the record the were editing was #3 in the list, it would move up to the first row now, but the ListView is still highlighting row 3.

I am capturing a GUID in just setting it to "display:none" on the  tag. So I have a unique to work with if I need to.

Is there a way to accomplish this in C# code-behind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is that on complete of the AJAX sort use jquery to reset the style of all the rows of the table back to thier default settings and then use the unique ID selector to find the edit row and set the background of that.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. I can just use a class on that <tr> tag. I'll try it out tomorrow.